# Selective histogram in R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

How would you implement something like this in R?

- [Selection histogram](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/selection_histogram.html)

Utilizing the scatterplot selection is the hard part. I haven't seen anything similar in Shiny or plotly.

Comment: It's actually not that hard. Read this tutorial on interactive plots in shiny: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html.  You'll want to use `brush` and the `brushedPoints` function to select rows of data from your `ggplot`, which can then be used to render another plot.

Comment: You should first try some thing on your own so that it becomes helpful to us also to track and help.

Comment: @divibisan thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody needs it in the future.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyUI(basicPage(
  titlePanel("Number of forward gears of selected cars"),

  plotOutput("plot",brush = "plot_brush"),
  plotOutput("histo",height="200px")
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({  
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg,color=as.factor(gear))) + geom_point() + labs(y=  'Miles per gallon',x = 'Weight (1000 lbs)')  
  })

  output$histo <- renderPlot({  
    selected_points<-brushedPoints(mtcars, input$plot_brush, xvar = "wt", yvar = "mpg")
    ggplot(data=selected_points, aes(selected_points$gear,fill = as.factor(gear))) + geom_bar() + labs(x="Forward Gears", y="Count")   + coord_flip() +theme_minimal()    
    })
})
```

[image: Result]